# Group WHILE loop results in specific rows

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I use while loop to output data from my database but i need to group specific row in my case i want to group the `Student no.` and `Name` as image 2 show.
my current output return like image below:
[image]

**this I want to output:**

[image]

**update**

**sql**

```
$sql  = "SELECT * ";
    $sql .= "FROM registration ";
    $sql .= "WHERE Sem = '{$sem}' ";
    if($course !==""){
    $sql .= "AND Course = '{$course}' ";
    }
    if($year_level !==""){
    $sql .= "AND YearLevel = '{$year_level}' "; 
    }
    $sql .= "AND SY = '{$sy}' ";
    //$sql .= "GROUP BY StudentNumber ";
    $sql .= "ORDER BY Lastname, SubjectCode ASC";
    $row_set = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

**php**

```
<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($row_set)){?>


  <table class="subjectInProfile" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <th>Student No.</th>
      <th>Student Name</th>
      <th>Subject Code</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>LecUnit/LabUnit</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row_set)){ ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['StudentNumber']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo encodeToUtf8($row['LastName'].', '.$row['FirstName']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['SubjectCode']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['Description']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['LecUnit'].'/'.$row['LabUnit']); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } mysqli_free_result($row_set); ?>
  </table>

   <?php } else {
  echo "<h1 class=\"noRecordFound\">No record found.</h1>";
  }?>

  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Share some code please. What does the database structure look like? 1 table? 2 tables?

Comment: You should change the query rather than try to do the sorting in php. Can you show the current query?

Comment: Your requirement is NOT related to "GROUP BY" in SQL. You are wanting to suppress the output of some values to make the output more attractive, which you should do in PHP/HTML (your "presentation layer"). Within SQL grouping is used to calculate aggregate values like sum, average, maximum and it does NOT conditionally suppress display of values. I would suggest removing the MySQL tag by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `order by LastName, FirstName, StudentNumber, SubjectCode` to ensure the rows for a single student are consecutive.

Then, you want to echo out the student number and name only if you haven't already. I'd keep track of the last student number echoed, and if the student number of the current row differs, output it. So your code becomes:

```
. . .
<?php $lastStudentNumber = null; ?>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row_set)){ ?>
<tr>
  <?php if($lastStudentNumber !== $row['StudentNumber']) { ?>
  <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['StudentNumber']); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo encodeToUtf8($row['LastName'].', '.$row['FirstName']); ?></td>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php $lastStudentNumber = $row['StudentNumber']; ?>
  <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['SubjectCode']); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['Description']); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['LecUnit'].'/'.$row['LabUnit']); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } mysqli_free_result($row_set); ?>
. . .
```